# How to plot two different graphs in python

Tags: python

I want to get two lines in the same graph.

This is my code:

```
    x=sorted(true_strain)
    y=sorted(true_stress_1)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.title('$Tensile Stress-Strain Curve$')
    plt.xlabel('True Strain [-]')
    plt.ylabel('$True Stress (MPa)$')
    a=(true_stress_2)
    b=sorted(true_strain)
    plt.plot(a,b)
```

But the image I got is blank. What am I missing?

Comment: What library are you using? I don't see any imports or anything here to determine what you're using.

Comment: Do you intend for b to be true_strain and a to be true_stress_2? Because you have x as true_strain and y as true_stress, so it looks like you're swapping independent and dependent variables, which could throw the plot.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't actually called plt.show(), try adding it at the bottom.

```
x=sorted(true_strain)
y=sorted(true_stress_1)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('$Tensile Stress-Strain Curve$')
plt.xlabel('True Strain [-]')
plt.ylabel('$True Stress (MPa)$')
a=(true_stress_2)
b=sorted(true_strain)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```